# Transferring XTZ with only a private key

Tags: tezos-client, tezbox

I have an account and all the account details (private key, etc) that I created via tezos-client. I had a tezos-node, but it's been broken for a month now due to the snapshot functionality and some other bugs all of which I've filed in gitlab.

So I can't use tezos-client to transfer funds as my tezos node can't bootstrap anymore.

If I try to import the account into TezBox it wants the seed phrase which I don't have. How can I transfer funds from this tezos-client based account?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use your tezos-client with a public tezos-node? And if your current tezos-client doesn't work for some reason, you can recompile one (and you don't have to bootstrap the node). If you don't want to recompile one (or can't for some reason), perhaps you could use the docker image?

Comment: Thanks. I am using the docker image. And you do need to bootstrap the node. 'Waiting for the node to be bootstrapped before injection...'  I don't know how you can use a public node to do this because the public node will either have to have the private key or know the address of the signer for the private key. Only my node knows that info.